# Почему возникает ошибка вида unrecognized expression: :nth-child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код. Он должен подсвечивать строку текста, в зависимости от того, что мы получили из геттера `proc.getNumber_line_one()`

```
$("#proc1").click(function() {
    proc.process_one();
    process_run_info_text = "Number of Process: " + proc.getNumbProc;
    line_process_one = proc.getNumber_line_one();
    console.log(line_process_one);
    //$("#left_process span:nth-child(3)").attr("style", "color:red");
    line_process_one = 3;
    $("#left_process span:nth-child(line_process_one)").attr("style", "color:red");
});
```

Но при нажатии на `button` возникает ошибка:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Когда прописываю `$("#left_process span:nth-child(2)").attr("style", "color:red");`, то есть явно указываю строку подсветки, все ок. А так не работает. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `line_process_one`, в этом случае, у вас воспринимается как часть строки.
Правильно было бы сделать так:

```
$("#left_process span:nth-child(" + line_process_one + ")").attr("style", "color:red");
```

Answer (score 2):

[Параметром для селектора `nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) должно быть число либо выражение, в данном случае передается строка `line_process_one` которая не соответствует ни одному формату выражения.

Для интерполирования переменных в строках можно использовать [Template literals из ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
$(`#left_process span:nth-child(${line_process_one})`).attr("style", "color:red");
```

Comment: Поставил вам плюс за ссылку на статью и пример интерполирования переменных

Comment: @VenZell, :-D будущее уже рядом. Добавил еще ссылку на справку по селектору